# Why does my command: "rm -rf *" not delete all the files in a directory?

Tags: bash, rm

Most of the files are gone, but I'm still left with these two files:

".RData" and ".Rhistory"

Why is this the case? I'm working with R, but I don't know what those files are.

Afterwards, I can individually remove them without needing to use sudo.

Comment: does that happen with only these two files or with all hidden files ?

Comment: just those two files. I was able to remove other hidden directories

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. I had copied from a previous directory and thought I copied all hidden files, but they weren't actually copied.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`*` only includes visible files.  If you want to delete both those and the hidden ones, use:

```
rm -rf * .*
```

#### The dotglob option

With bash, we can change this behavior and unhide files.  To illustrate, let's create two files, one hidden and one not:

```
$ touch unhidden .hide1
$ ls *
unhidden
```

As you can see, only the unhidden one is shown by `ls *`.  Now let's set the `dotglob` option:

```
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ ls *
.hide1  unhidden
```

Both files appear now.  We can, of course, turn dotglob off if we want:

```
$ shopt -u dotglob
$ ls *
unhidden
```

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> When a pattern is  used  for  pathname  expansion,  the character 
>   "."  at the start of a name or immediately following a slash must be
>   matched explicitly, unless the shell option dotglob is set.  When
>   matching a pathname, the slash character must always be  matched 
>   explicitly.   In  other cases, the ``.''  character is not treated
>   specially.  See the description of shopt below under SHELL BUILTIN
>   COMMANDS for a description of the nocaseglob, nullglob, failglob, and
>   dotglob shell options.

In other words, *pathname expansion* ignores files whose names begin with `.` unless the `.` is explicitly specified.

#### Safety issues

To avoid unpleasant surprises, `rm` will refuse to remove the current directory `.` and the parent directory `..` even if you specify them on the command line:

```
$ rm -rf .*
rm: refusing to remove ‘.’ or ‘..’ directory: skipping ‘.’
rm: refusing to remove ‘.’ or ‘..’ directory: skipping ‘..’
```

Comment: @Rahul Yes, good point.  Answer updated with rm's warnings.

Comment: Can I explicitly exclude the `.` and `..` directories?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the directory is correct then

`sudo rm -rf * .*`

Comment: how does that differ from @John1024's answer ?

Comment: sudo for permission based issues.

Comment: Some people get into the habit of using `sudo` on every command, or at least every command that has ever failed (regardless of whether the failure was permissions-based). Other people get into the habit of aiming loaded firearms at their feet. These habits are highly similar: they both create a high probability that you will eventually shoot yourself in the foot. Don't use `sudo` unless you understand the reason why the command will work with `sudo` and fail without it.

Comment: What stops .* from expanding to ..    ?  and then you blow away the directory one level up and everything in it ?

Comment: @Criggie See John1024's answer. In short, `rm` special cases `.` and `..` and doesn't remove them.